# Decrease query size: Append new data to Big Query table based on latest date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to append new data from `table_a` to `table_b` every day by using a scheduled query in Google Big Query. See example below.

However, when I write the `SELECT` statement which appends to `table_b` the query size gets really large.

If I compare the dynamic query to the one where I use a fixed date (here: `30.05.2020`) the query size tenfolds:

```
SELECT
date_a as date_b,
col1,
col2,
col3 
FROM `project.dataset.table_a`
WHERE
  date_a > (select max(date_b) from `project.dataset.table_b`)
ORDER by date_b
```

**table_a**(partioned on `date_a`; total size over 200GB) (this example is simplified as I am doing other `JOINs` and `UNIONs` etc. in the query)

```
+------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
|    date_a  |  col1   |  col2   | col3 |    others    |    others    |
+------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
| 27.05.2020 | henry   | muller  | 100$ | not relevant | not relevant |
| 28.05.2020 | jamie   | fox     | 200$ | not relevant | not relevant |
| 29.05.2020 | richard | branson | 20$  | not relevant | not relevant |
| 30.05.2020 | jannet  | jackson | 50$  | not relevant | not relevant |
| 31.05.2020 | michael | jackson | 90$  | not relevant | not relevant |
+------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+--------------+
```

**table_b** (not partioned, total size less than 50MB)

```
+------------+---------+---------+------+
|    date_b  |  col1   |  col2   | col3 |
+------------+---------+---------+------+
| 27.05.2020 | henry   | muller  | 100$ |
| 28.05.2020 | jamie   | fox     | 200$ |
| 29.05.2020 | richard | branson | 20$  |
| 30.05.2020 | jannet  | jackson | 50$  |
+------------+---------+---------+------+
```

**Question:**

Have you got a tip for me how I can read out the MAX(date_b) before or another query-reducing suggestion?

Comment: Is `table_a` partitioned on `date_a`?

Comment: yes it is partioned.

Comment: Have you read this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input) about optimizing query performance and reducing costs?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was addressed & answered in another thread I didn't see before.

Here is the other question: [How to choose the latest partition in BigQuery table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733826/how-to-choose-the-latest-partition-in-bigquery-table)

Here is the 'official' answer/ help from Google on this matter: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pseudo_column_queries_that_scan_all_partitions