# Is there a way to declare a variable in a data studio custom query?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I've got an issue similiar to the one described here :
[Pruning BigQuery partitions with Data studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697079/pruning-bigquery-partitions-with-data-studio)

I want to declare a variable to run a custom query in data studio.

For example :

```
DECLARE usd_to_eur_rate FLOAT64;
SET usd_to_eur_rate = 0.8;   

SELECT itemPrice_USD*usd_to_eur_rate as itemPrice_EUR
FROM `dataset.table`
```

Query works in BigQuery but not in data studio.

As in the above mentioned topic, I get error message :

```
Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.

Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set
```

I've read the comment solving the issue :

```
DECLARE statement don't work in DataStudio, 
because the whole custom query is wrapped in an outer select 
so this syntax becomes invalid SELECT ........ FROM (DECLARE usd_to_eur_rate ..............................)
```

Still, I haven't figured out a workaround ...

Do you guys have an idea of an alternative syntax that could work into data studio custom query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

@Pentium10, thanks for precision.

I'll post an answer here with how I used this advice to finally get the query work in data studio :

Instead of

```
DECLARE usd_to_eur_rate FLOAT64;
SET usd_to_eur_rate = 0.8;   

SELECT itemPrice_USD * usd_to_eur_rate AS itemPrice_EUR
FROM `dataset.table`
```

I've been using :

```
WITH vars AS
(
    SELECT 0.8 AS usd_to_eur_rate 
)

SELECT itemPrice_USD * (SELECT usd_to_eur_rate FROM vars) AS itemPrice_EUR
FROM `dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to create a table to hold that value, and select the value from the table.

As I wrote on the other thread all DataStudio queries bust be wrappable in outer select statement.